# related_query_name's default / fallback behaviour has changed in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

I am updating a project from Django 1.8 to Django 1.11. It's a somewhat mature / complex project with a lot of models and queries.

It seems that a backwards incompatible change was made in Django 1.10, namely the default behaviour of `ForeignKey.related_query_name`. In Django 1.10, `related_query_name` falls back to the model's `default_related_name` - in Django 1.8 this was not the case. This change is apparent in the docs:

Django 1.9: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name

Django 1.10: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name

Almost all of my models have `default_related_name` defined, yet no `ForeignKey`s have `related_query_name` set. This means that essentially all of my database queries that traverse relationships are invalid!

Am I doomed to rewrite all my queries, or add `related_query_name` to everything? Or is there some way to retain the old functionality?